# Use bash-type `${i%.mp3}` syntax with xargs?

Tags: bash, syntax, xargs

Example of usage (contrived!): rename .mp3 files to .txt.

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 -I'file' mv file ${file%.mp3}.txt
```

This doesn't work, so I've resorted to piping `find`'s output through `sed -e 's/.mp3//g'`, which does the trick.

Seems a bit hackish though; **is there a way to use the usual bash `${x%y}` syntax?**

Comment: You've asked a question, which has no pure answer.  Or at least an answer you're willing to accept, as you never checked accept.  My 'hackish' way, is piping `find ... | sed ... | xargs ...`. Which you stated as your alternative method.   So to clearly break it down, `xargs` itself, does not support Bash variable expansion.  Can you work around this, In many different methods?? As you already knew, Yes! Can you do this 'purely' in `xargs`?  No!

Answer (score 2):

No, `xargs -0 -I'file' mv file ${file%.mp3}.txt` will not work because the `file` variable will be expanded by the xargs program and not the shell. Actually it is not quite correct to refer to it as a variable, it is called "replace-str" in the manual of xargs.

Update: To just use xargs and bash (and no sed or similar) you can of course let xargs start a bash process which then can do whatever substitution you want:

```
find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c \
'while [ -n "$1" ]; do mv "$1" "${1%.mp3}.txt" ; shift; done;' "bash"
```

Comment: Any way to have the shell expand the expression, before xargs does its thing?

Comment: The reason for the "bash" is  it is interpreted as $0 so $1 becomes what is fed in by xargs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | parallel -0 mv {} {.}.txt
```

If your file names do not contain \n (newline) this will work too:

```
find -name '*.mp3' | parallel mv {} {.}.txt
```

Watch the intro video to learn more about GNU Parallel http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another suggestion, even though it doesn't use the shell's substitution mechanism, but instead, sed's.

```
find -name '*.mp3' -print |
sed -e 's/\.mp3$//' -e "s/.*/mv '&\.mp3' '&\.txt'/" |
sh
```

In other words, create an `mv` command line for each file name, and pass the result to `sh`.

This will fail if any of the files have an apostrophe (single quote) in their file name.  I mainly post this to counter the "if all you have is xargs, every problem will look like a nail" syndrome.

Not all seds have exactly the same syntax.  In particular, I'm not 100% sure you can have multiple -e arguments on some crufty old SunOS (look for the XPG-compatible sed in something like `/usr/ucb/blah/barf/vomit/xpg4/bin/sed`)

Comment: For contemporary Bash, sure.  But it's not portable back to really old Bash versions, which the OP here might be suffering from, so I tried to make this reasonably portable.  This should work even in Heirloom `sh` and other similarly encumbered shells.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' | while read -r F
do
  mv "$F" "${F%.mp3}.txt"
done
```

Bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*.mp3
do
    mv "$file" "${file%.mp3}.txt"
done
```

Comment: I know how to do this; the purpose of the question is to see if it's possible to do this with xargs, and have it not immediately expand replace-str (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl rename.pl 's/\.mp3$/.txt/' *.mp3  
# Or **/*.mp3 for zsh and bash with specific settings set, for a recursive 
# rename.
```

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/pl_src/rename/rename.html